# Is there a convention for factory method in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

For ObjectiveC there is [Apple's convention](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html) for naming class factory methods.

It has to start with name of the class: `[NSMutableArray array]`.

Is there a convention for naming class factory methods in Swift?

Alex

Comment: maybe no, but you can take a look at this https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Swift API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/)

> Begin names of factory methods with “make”, e.g. x.makeIterator()